# datasource.getConnection() not working in Springboot application

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

My db properties are kept in application-test.properties (I am running Springboot application in test profile) and the Datasource is referred through @Autowired annotation. It throws NullPointerException when I try to use datasource.getConnection().

I have referred similar questions and mostly all of them include some solutions with bean xml configurations. In my case I am not explicitly using any bean configurations. Every datasource properties are kept in application-test.properties file and I am referring through it using Datasource. I am a newbie to Springboot and any help would be great.

**My repository class**

```
@Repository
public class ActualUserDetailsDAO {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    public String getPriorityType(String idNo) throws Exception {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String cxPriorityType = null;
        int count = 0;

        try {                    
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
            String sql = ConfigurationHandler.getInstance().getConfigValue("sample.query");
            ......................
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ................
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ..............
        } finally {
            .................
                  }
        return cxPriorityType;
    }
```

**My application properties**

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
server.port=8180

# Datasource settings
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.name=camst2

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@..................
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

# Tomcat JDBC settings
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=100
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=100
#spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=6000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=30000
#spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-connect=true
#spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
#spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-return=true

# Tomcat AccessLog
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=access_log
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=/tomcat/logs
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%h %l %u %t %r %s %b %D
```

**My application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there - can you please add the entire stack trace?

Comment: Sorry. I cannot share the entire stack trace due to some confidential data. However I can assure that request is been received and it is coming to the point till datasource.getConnection() (Based on my logs).                                                                  Then the exception thrown like this,                                                              
exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was in my controller class. I was creating an instance of the my repository class by myself. I should have used @Autowired instead.

```
@RestController
public class ActualUserDetails implements ActualUserDetailsInt {

@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getActualUserDetails(@PathVariable("idNo") String idNo, @RequestParam("lob") String lob,
@RequestParam("offerSellingType") String offerSellingType) {

      //do something
      ActualUserDetailsDAO actualUserDetailsDAO = new ActualUserDetailsDAO();
      actualUserDetailsDAO.getPriorityType(idNo);
      //do something
```

I changed this into following.

```
@RestController
public class ActualUserDetails implements ActualUserDetailsInt {

  @Autowired
  ActualUserDetailsDAO actualUserDetailsDAO;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = 
  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> getActualUserDetails(@PathVariable("idNo") String idNo,
  @RequestParam("lob") String lob,                                           
  @RequestParam("offerSellingType") String offerSellingType) {

      //do something
      actualUserDetailsDAO.getPriorityType(idNo);
      //do something
```

Manually creating object of my repository class did not detected dataSource defined inside it. Autowiring my repository class in my controller class seems to solve this problem.

If your data source is not been detected for any reason, I strongly recommend to have a deeper look on your code.
Following are some of the things to look for when this kind of error happens.

- Look for the correct folder structure (application properties file
  reside under resources folder)
- If you are running Spring in a different profile (say test
  profile), make sure relevant configurations are written in
  application-test.properties
- Check for proper annotation in relevant classes
- Make sure your application properties are not overridden by any other
  configurations